# activate quad buffered stereo with sfml or openGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, sfml, stereo-3d

My program works perfectly fine in a normal 3D with one buffer, it is coded with SFML window management.
I would like to add quad buffered stereo, therefore i changed my drawing code to the following :

```
        glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK_LEFT);
    camera->OnMouseMotion(sf::Vector2i(-1,0));
    for (auto i = objects->cbegin(); i != objects->cend(); ++i)
        (*i)->draw(camera);
    glFlush();
    glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK_RIGHT);
    camera->OnMouseMotion(sf::Vector2i(2,0));
    for (auto i = objects->cbegin(); i != objects->cend(); ++i)
        (*i)->draw(camera);
    glFlush();
    camera->OnMouseMotion(sf::Vector2i(-1,0));
```

Notice that my camera changed are not perfectly right and i know i will have to change these, right now i am focusing on displaying an image just using quad buffered stereo. I noticed in all examples of programs using this stereo that they were initialising the window with something like this :

```
    type = GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_STEREO;
  glutInitDisplayMode(type);
```

Using SFML, such function isn't available, my questions are :
Can i use a low-level openGL function to achieve the same result ? Can i use another window managing library with SFML ? Should i forget SFML for my program and completly change it to another one ?

Comment: Before ripping your hair on this topic, please first make sure that your system actually *supports* quad buffer stereo. Technically all modern GPUs can do it, but for marketing reasons historically the function has been disabled on consumer grade products. NVidia still keeps quad buffer stereo tied to its Quadro series of professional GPU cards (some evil tongues say, the *Quad* in Quadro is for quadbuffer stereo); AMD recently opened up and supports it for their Radeon cards, given recent enough drivers.

Comment: @datenwolf Yes no worries about that, there is already a programm running with quad buffered stereo on the same computer. it's a quadro 5000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SFML doesn't have an initialisation function, it creates openGL context automatically, two things you can do :

- Modify SFML sources you are using, and try to add somewhere in the window creation function your parameter
- change your display library to create the openGL context, however you may or not keep SFML 2D drawing functions, i am not sure these are gonna work if you create your context with glut for example.

EDIT : after a small check, you cannot create a context with another library and still use SFML for drawing simple 2D forms, i am afraid you are forced to let SFML go.